# How to Add Rating Bar that shows up on button hover in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, web-applications, ratingbar

[image]

Hey guys
I am new to flutter, especially to the UI component. I am trying to build a screen on which there is a star icon on the edge of the screen. And on hovering up on the star icon, a rating bar shows up, the user gives the rating by touching either of the stars. And when the touch is moved away from the icon/rating bar; the rating bar disappears.

Any pointers to build this functionality will be very huge help.

I tried this code as per the suggestions of salim.elkh:

```
GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
            Container(
               width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
               margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
               horizontal: 20),
               child: RatingBarIndicator(
                       rating: 2.75,
                       itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        const Icon(
                                 Icons.star,
                                 color: Colors.amber,
                                  ),
                        itemCount: 5,
                        itemSize: 50.0,
                        direction: Axis.horizontal,
                           ),
                          );
                       },
                     child: const Icon(
                           Icons.star,
                           color: themeColor0,
                                ), // Show the icon when long press is false
                     )
```

but it is not working. When I long press on the icon, rating bar does not show up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Flutter,

You can use a GestureDetector to capture long-press (onLongPress) and when it stops(onLongPressEnd).
onLongPress you can show the Rating widget, and onLongPressEnd you can hide it.
For more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

For the rating widget, you can use a popular package that handles this:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar

EDIT:
You can use an overlay to show the rating bar on top of your widget. Here is a useful tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOEyJ0ct0Sg&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com

Comment: Thanks. And how can i add a rating bar to show up horizontally and not occupying the entire page when longPressing it? Do i need a separate pagebuilder/builder for it?

Comment: Use a SizedBox or a Container and set the dimensions you prefer :)

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the code as shared in the post (could not share in the comments due to characterlimit). Can you please share further pointers on what is missing in that piece of code.